# Get items within GridView Windows 8

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How can I get (or loop through) all the items in a gridview? Following XAML generates a grid of items that are tappable/clickable

```xml
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    TabIndex="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Padding="116,136,116,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsSwipeEnabled="false">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250" Tapped="Grid_Tapped" RightTapped="Grid_RightTapped">
                <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentState}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="12"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I need to be able to loop through each of these elements and update their values. This is how I try to do it but can't

```cs
foreach (var item in itemGridView.Items)
{
    var _Container = itemGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

    //Once i have the contrainer i know i can access its childern but this line of code throws error 
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to being able to do what I want to do here?

Or if there is RowDataBound like event in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update values you don't need to get container. For example you have a data class:

```
    public class mydemotable
{
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is example how to fill this class and loop through elements with changing Name value:

```
     mydemotable demoitem = new mydemotable
        {
            Name = "Skywalker",
            CurrentState = "lalala"
        };

        ObservableCollection<mydemotable> items = new ObservableCollection<mydemotable>();
        items.Add(demoitem);

        itemGridView.DataContext = items;


        foreach (mydemotable item in itemGridView.Items)
        {
            item.Name = "Alex"; 
        }
```